# What is the pythonic way of downloading hdf5 files from http server?

Tags: python, urllib, hdf5

I am trying to download a hdf5 file from http server. I can do this with python subprocess module and wget, but I feel like I am cheating

```
    # wget solution
    import subprocess
    url = 'http://url/to/file.h5' 
    subprocess(['wget', '--proxy=off', url])
```

I can also use the urllib and request modules for downloading images like this:

```
    # requests solution
    url2 = 'http://url/to/image.png'
    r = requests.get(url2)
    with open('image.png', 'wb') as img:
    img.write(r.content)

    # urllib solution
    urllib.urlretrieve(url2, 'outfile.png')
```

However, when I try to download hdf5-file with this method and run shell command 'file' I get:

```
    >file test.h5 
    >test.h5: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Here is the header from requests.get() (not sure if it helps)

```
    {'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
    'content-length': '413399',
    'date': 'Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:51:06 GMT',
    'etag': 'W/"413399-1361177055000"',
    'last-modified': 'Mon, 18 Feb 2013 08:44:15 GMT',
    'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1'}
```

**Should I just use wget throug subprocess or is there a pythonic solution?**

**Solution:**
The problem was caused by the fact that I didn't disable the proxy before I tried to download the file and because of that, the transfer was intercepted. This piece of code did the trick.

```
    import urllib2
    proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    url = 'http://url/to/file.h5'

    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    r = opener.open(req)
    result = r.read()

    with open('my_file.h5', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(result)
```

Comment: With urllib, have you actually looked at the file? It sounds more like the request is being intercepted and you're downloading an html document instead of the png that you're looking for. So maybe you can find a better link?

Comment: You are correct, the request was intercepted! When I disabled the proxy and did some other stuff, I finally got the right file. This was my first post to SO. Is it ok to include my complete solution to the original question? Should I edit the title of the question somehow?

Comment: Yeah, you can just edit your question and then post your answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `urllib.geturl` to get the real URL (following the redirects) and then pass that to `urlretrieve`.